# Get all user ids from left join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, aggregate-functions

I am calculating score from answer table. Each answer has a difficulty level and score is differ with difficulty level so i write a sql query  to calculate it i successfully calculated the score but problem is when any user haven't played any one or more then one difficulty level then column is coming null. See below image for more clarification.
[image: Sql table snapshot]

My query is

```
select (IFNULL(k.l1_p*0.5,0)+IFNULL(k.l2_p*1,0)+IFNULL(k.l3_p*2,0)+IFNULL(k.l4_p*2.75,0)+IFNULL(k.l5_p*3.75,0)) as total,k.user_id from (select tab1.l1_p,tab5.user_id,tab2.l2_p,tab3.l3_p,tab4.l4_p,tab5.l5_p from (select count(id) as l1_p,user_id from wp_user_answers where answer=1 and difficulty=1 group by user_id) tab1 left join 
->         (select count(id) as l2_p,user_id from wp_user_answers where answer=1 and difficulty=2 group by user_id) tab2 on tab1.user_id=tab2.user_id left join 
->         (select count(id) as l3_p,user_id from wp_user_answers where answer=1 and difficulty=3 group by user_id) tab3  on tab3.user_id=tab2.user_id left join
->         (select count(id) as l4_p,user_id from wp_user_answers where answer=1 and difficulty=4 group by user_id) tab4  on tab3.user_id=tab4.user_id left join
->         (select count(id) as l5_p,user_id from wp_user_answers where answer=1 and difficulty=5 group by user_id) tab5  on tab4.user_id=tab5.user_id) k;
```

result of this query is

[image]

you can see `user_id :169` becomes Null. I want all user_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use **LEFT JOIN**, You can directly got desired result using **Aggregate function** and **Conditional Statements**.

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, 
      (SUM(CASE WHEN difficulty = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 0.5 + 
       SUM(CASE WHEN difficulty = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 + 
       SUM(CASE WHEN difficulty = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 2.0 + 
       SUM(CASE WHEN difficulty = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 2.75 + 
       SUM(CASE WHEN difficulty = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 3.75 
     ) AS total
FROM wp_user_answers 
WHERE answer = 1 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this simple answer.